# Injection error, using ui-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, bootstrap-modal

`Unknown provider: $confirmModalProvider <- $confirmModal <- confirmModalCtrl`

Why am I getting this error? I'm trying to use AngularJS UI Bootstrap to open a modal and get the result. I get this error when I trigger `$scope.deleteQuestion()`. Any idea what I'd doing wrong here?

```
var crtPromoCtrl = angular.module('crtPromoCtrl', ['crtPromoSrv']);

crtPromoCtrl.controller('surveyCtrl', ['$scope', '$modal', 'surveySrv', function($scope, $modal, surveySrv)
{
        $scope.questions = surveySrv.getQuestions();

    $scope.editQuestion = function(index)
    {
        surveySrv.setEditQuestion(index);
    };

    $scope.deleteQuestion = function(index)
    {
        var confirmModal = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'confirm-delete.html',
            controller: 'confirmModalCtrl',
            size: 'sm'
        });

        confirmModal.result.then(function(msg)
        {
            console.log(msg);
        });

        return false;
    };
}]);

crtPromoCtrl.controller('confirmModalCtrl', ['$scope', '$confirmModal', function($scope, $confirmModal)
{
    $scope.yes = function()
    {
        $confirmModal.close('yes');
    };

    $scope.no = function()
    {
        $confirmModal.dismiss('no');
    };
}]);
```

EDIT: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Comment: what is `$confirmModal` in controller? do you want to access `confirmModal` of `crtPromoCtrl`

Comment: See the script here: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal. That's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: is it `$confirmModal` or `confirmModal` ?

Comment: @AkashShinde it should be `$modalInstance` instead of `$confirmModal ` check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You second controller should use `$modalInstance` instead of `$confirmModal`

> Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance)
>   dependency.

**Code**

```
crtPromoCtrl.controller('confirmModalCtrl', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', function($scope, $modalInstance) {
    $scope.yes = function() {
        $modalInstance.close('yes');
    };

    $scope.no = function() {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('no');
    };
}]);
```

Comment: This did the trick!. I thought the name `modalInstance` was interchangeable as long as it macthed the var name in the first controller. Thanks!